# Fetch data request to nested JSON object error - React/Next.JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I'm having problems fetching data from my API and I get this error. I have attached the JSON format below as I believe it is an issue with my structure. When I use a different res URL with objects nested inside an array, it works. But for my data, it is not. Can anyone help me please?

"Index.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object. But found undefined instead"

```
import Layout from '../comps/Layout';
import Link from 'next/link';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

const Index = props => (
<Layout>
    //List of movies here
</Layout>
);

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.what-song.com/api/recent-movies')
    const data = await res.json()

    console.log(`Data: ${data}`)

}

export default Index;
```

[image]

Comment: That code structure is a little bit weird...can you post the code that is using your Index component? Also, I don't think you can attach functions like that in react, unless you are using a class. (I am talking about the way you are creating your `getInitialProps `)

Answer (score 1):

The `getInitialProps` method basically supposed to set your component initial `props`. But, in your case you are returning nothing.

So, change your code to

```
Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
    const res = await fetch('https://www.what-song.com/api/recent-movies')
    const data = await res.json()

    console.log(`Data: ${data}`)
    return { data }; // <-- set whatever key you want.
}
```

For your [reference](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)